# I am using react-native-swiper-flatlist , but I cannot figure it out how to use scrollToIndex on button press

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I am using *react-native-swiper-flatlist* , I want to scroll forward to some index by tapping button but no clue how to do it. Although I am very beginner to react native development.

I have searched alot but nothing helps, I get an error of undefined is not an object this2.swiper.scrollToIndex'

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SwiperFlatList
      ref={swiper => {
        this.swiper = swiper;
      }}
      data={[
        { key: "a" },
        { key: "b" },
        { key: "c" },
        { key: "d" },
        { key: "e" }
      ]}
      index={0}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View>
          <Image
            style={styles.child}
            source={require("../../assets/advertisementtwo.png")}
          />
          <Image
            style={styles.child}
            source={require("../../assets/advertisementtwo.png")}
          />
          <Image
            style={styles.child}
            source={require("../../assets/advertisementtwo.png")}
          />
          <Image
            style={styles.child}
            source={require("../../assets/advertisementtwo.png")}
          />
          <Button
            title={"Next"}
            onPress={this.swiper.scrollToIndex(1, true)}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </View>
);
```

}

Should swipe on button click

[Here is the screenshot of the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g5Qg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `ref='swiper'` as a `SwiperFlatList` prop,

**Example**

```
<SwiperFlatList ref='swiper'/>
```

`this.refs.swiper._scrollToIndex(2)`

Comment: I have figured out the problem "onPress={this.swiper.scrollToIndex(3)}"
should be replaced by 

 onPress={() => {  this.refs.swiper._scrollToIndex(3) }}

thanks

Comment: You need to set `this.refs.swiper.scrollToIndex(2)` and declare reference as example

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using React `hook` instead of `class`, you can do sth like that to utilise the `scrollToIndex` function

```
//First,  make a ref for storing the swiper instance inside your swiper compoent
const swiperRef = useRef<any>({});

//Second, store the reference
<SwiperFlatList
    ref={(component) => { swiperRef.current._swiper = component; }}
>

//Later on, you can call the function like this
swiperRef.current._swiper.scrollToIndex({index: 2})
```